# How can I get the output of a Python subprocess command that contains a pipe?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I have:

```
cmd_array = ['head', '-n', str(source_noise_end), "data/noise/" + source + '_16k.dat', '|', 'tail', '-' + str(source_noise_start)]
source_noise = subprocess.check_output(cmd_array)
```

The command is valid when I type it into Linux. I get `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['head', '-n', '2366468', 'data/noise/white_16k.dat', '|', 'tail', '-2183988']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path instead of `data/...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this :

```
import subprocess

# cmd contains shell command
cmd="your command shell"

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=None,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
# The output from your shell command
result=process.stdout.readlines()
if len(result) >= 1:
    for line in result:
        print(line.decode("utf-8"))
```