# How to run unoconv via subprocess in django python?

Tags: python, django, subprocess, unoconv

If I run unoconv -f pdf test_pdf.docx in terminal, it's working fine. But if I run it in subprocess, I got this error

```
subprocess.run(['unoconv', '-f', 'pdf', path],  shell=True)

unoconv: Cannot find a suitable pyuno library and python binary combination in 
/usr/lib/libreoffice
ERROR: No module named 'uno'

unoconv: Cannot find a suitable office installation on your system.
ERROR: Please locate your office installation and send your feedback to:
   http://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues
```

Please help me resolve this problem

Comment: can you add your code inside your question? and also your command unoconv that work

Comment: I added code, thank you.

Comment: pls add also your command shell that work

Comment: and check my reply to a similar question that I have replied    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59462803/how-can-i-get-the-output-of-a-python-subprocess-command-that-contains-a-pipe/59462840#59462840

Comment: this command `unoconv -f pdf test_pdf.docx` it worked on terminal.

Comment: I tried, but now has no any error but still not create pdf file. And the result is empty `[]`

Comment: is linux you SO right ?

Comment: yes, I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: I made an example in google colab(ubuntu) and worked...

Comment: check your directory...like you I have []  as result ...but the file was created

Comment: your code like this:
`cmd="unoconv -f pdf -o %s %s"%(path1, path)`


`process = 
 subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=None,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204789/discussion-between-giovanisalazar-and-vinhvuong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this throws the error, also there are already a lot of closed [issues](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ERROR%3A%20No%20module%20named%20%27uno%27) on GitHub related to the issue.

The most useful answers are [49#issuecomment-416317222](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv/issues/49#issuecomment-416317222) and [49#issuecomment-464011493](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv/issues/49#issuecomment-464011493). It is hard to believe but the problem came from 2012 and still does not has a proper fix.

Comment: it worked  if I run on local, when I deploy with apache2, it not working

Comment: What have you used? And how you're deploying?

Comment: I'm using wsgi via apache2

Comment: I followed this: 

Try to copy from /usr/bin/unoconv to /usr/local/bin/unoconv.
And try to replace #!/usr/bin/env python3 on #!/usr/bin/python3 in unoconv file.

Comment: I guess you call it on some view? Can you show the code? Have you tried the same on the dev server and it is not working?

Comment: this is my code:  subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=None,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: yes it also working, if I run with python manage. runserver on server

Comment: So the problem still exists? What do you mean by "it's not working with apache2"? Can you provide more information on it?

Comment: I think problem when run django app via apache2, Have you any suggest for me?

Comment: I think the problem somewhere else. If it works locally then I don't see possible problems with apache2 itself. It's quite hard to say what can be wrong.