# How to split the dynamic array values one by one using Python?

Tags: python, linux, list

We are getting the array value while printing. Getting the below output. Command:

```
import subprocess
output = [subprocess.check_output("kapacitor list tasks | grep -i enabled | cut -d ' ' -f1", shell=True)]
```

While printing the array:

```
`['tAlert_ALL_metrics_cpu\ntAlert_ALL_metrics_memory_usage\ntAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline\ntAlert_NN_WMS_endpoint-message-count_MSE\ntAlert_NN_ecom_version_check\ntAlert_NN_ecom_version_check_all_farms\ntAlert_NN_metrics_fileSystem\ntAlert_NWNA_metrics_fileSystem\n'] `
```

The expected output is like below:

```
output[0]= tAlert_ALL_metrics_cpu\ntAlert_ALL_metrics_memory_usage
output[1]= tAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline
output[2]= tAlert_NN_WMS_endpoint-message-count_MSE
```

And also while checking the length of arrary, it is displaying as 1

```
length = len(output)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the output is not a single line?

Comment: check this reply that I made before   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59462803/how-can-i-get-the-output-of-a-python-subprocess-command-that-contains-a-pipe/59462840#59462840

Comment: Now we getting output as a sing line. But we need to use the output as iterate

Comment: but if you execute kapacitor list tasks | grep -i enabled | cut -d in your console.....that return in a single line??

Comment: Yes it returns in single line like this tAlert_ALL_metrics_cpu\ntAlert_ALL_metrics_memory_usage\ntAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline\ntAlert_NN_WMS_endpoint-message-count_MSE\ntAlert_NN_ecom_version_check\ntAlert_NN_ecom_version_check_all_farms\ntAlert_NN_metrics_fileSystem\ntAlert_NWNA_metrics_fileSystem\n .. but in that line it showing like \n \n

Comment: For example now it printing like 1\n2\n3\n instead of that i need a each line for 1 2 3

Comment: I got this result (iterate ) https://pastebin.com/f9VEVt4B

Comment: Could you please confirm your code to get this output

Comment: I added below...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your output is

```
['tAlert_ALL_metrics_cpu\ntAlert_ALL_metrics_memory_usage\ntAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline\ntAlert_NN_WMS_endpoint-message-count_MSE\ntAlert_NN_ecom_version_check\ntAlert_NN_ecom_version_check_all_farms\ntAlert_NN_metrics_fileSystem\ntAlert_NWNA_metrics_fileSystem\n']
```

then you can make something like this :

```
output = ['tAlert_ALL_metrics_cpu\ntAlert_ALL_metrics_memory_usage\ntAlert_ALL_oracle_TBS_offline\ntAlert_NN_WMS_endpoint-message-count_MSE\ntAlert_NN_ecom_version_check\ntAlert_NN_ecom_version_check_all_farms\ntAlert_NN_metrics_fileSystem\ntAlert_NWNA_metrics_fileSystem\n']
outputlist = ''.join(output).split("\n")
for x in outputlist:
  print(x)
```